# composer cache not working on bitbucket pipeline build

Tags: php, docker, composer-php, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I got this in my bitbucket pipeline:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    develop:
    - step:
        caches:
          - composer
        name: unit tests - Delivery 
        image: totersapp/laravel-docker:phpredis
        script:
        - echo "memory_limit=512M" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memory-limit-php.ini
        - ln -f -s .env.pipelines .env
        - composer install 
        services:
        - postgres
        - redis
```

every time it run it is downloading the same files (even on the second run).. any ideas why?

This is the log for composer install:

```
+ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 199 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing kylekatarnls/update-helper (1.2.0): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (100%)
  - Installing ocramius/package-versions (1.4.2): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (30%)Downloading (35%)Downloading (65%)Downloading (95%)Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.13.1): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (100%)
```

### update: couldn't override default

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59542186/766570) I tried this:

```
- step:
    caches:
      - composer
    image: totersapp/laravel-docker:phpredis
    script:
    - composer install 
..
definitions:
caches:
  composer: /composer/cache
```

My problem is that I'm trying to call composer with a *custom* cache directory (in this case it's `/composer/cache`) but then again I don't have a way to call the composer install command while supplying the custom cache directory as an option (ie which is what the bitbucket tutorial is doing with bundle in this example:

```
 - bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

said another way, I cannot run something like this:

```
- composer install --cache-directory /composer/cache
```

## Update 2: discrepancy between composer.json and composer.lock

- First as a sanity check, I simply [cloned](https://bitbucket.org/toters/composer-cache/src/master/) the repo of [Nico
  Haase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1116230/nico-haase), and ran the pipelines, [passed](https://bitbucket.org/toters/composer-cache/addon/pipelines/home#!/results/3) ✅
- I copied and pasted the contents of his [bitbucket-pipelines.yml](https://bitbucket.org/toters/composer-cache/src/master/bitbucket-pipelines.yml) into mine, and I copied and pasted his [composer.json](https://bitbucket.org/toters/composer-cache/src/master/composer.json), I ran the pipeline. Failed ❌

But I got this in the composer install log:

```
+ composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --no-scripts
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Package operations: 199 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing kylekatarnls/update-helper (1.2.0): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (100%)
  - Installing ocramius/package-versions (1.4.2): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (30%)Downloading (35%)Downloading (65%)Downloading (95%)Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.13.1): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (100%)
```

- So i figured it's b/c the composer.lock file is out of sync with composer.json, so I added `composer update` to my pipeline.. this loaded from cache! ✅but failed here ❌:

```
    composer update
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
    Package operations: 108 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
      - Installing ocramius/package-versions (1.4.2): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (30%)Downloading (35%)Downloading (65%)Downloading (80%)Downloading (100%)
      - Installing symfony/flex (v1.6.0): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (100%)         
    Symfony operations: 1 recipe (4c6f09f5995a77b64f54dd80675d3bfe)
      - Configuring symfony/flex (>=1.0): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
    Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.0.*"
    Prefetching 106 packages 
      - Downloading (0%) (5%) (10%) (16%) (21%) (31%) (36%) (41%) (47%) (52%) (57%) (65%) (70%) (75%) (80%) (85%) (90%) (95%) (100%)
    Package operations: 106 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
      - Installing psr/container (1.0.0): Loading from cache
      - Installing symfony/service-contracts (v2.0.1): Loading from cache
      ..
      ..
    Executing script cache:clear [KO]
     [KO]
    Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
    !!  Fatal Error: composer.lock was created for PHP version 7.2.9 or higher but the current PHP version is 7.1.32.
```

note: in my original composer.json file, i found this line

```
  "config": {
        ..
        "cache-dir": "~/.cache/composer",
    },
```

so I removed that line, but that didn't help either.

Still digging (for the record this is what my composer.json [looks like](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/toters/onrA6z), i kept the `cache-dir` part in it for reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [a question on the Bitbucket forums](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Can-t-cache-Node-nor-Composer-in-Pipelines-amp-Deployment/qaq-p/707689), this can happen if the docker image you are using is putting the downloaded files in a unusual position. According to [the documentation about caches](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/caching-dependencies-895552876.html), the usual directory that is cached is `~/.composer/cache`, while the [docker file of the image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/totersapp/laravel-docker/phpredis/images/sha256-7b918176939385629c0557fb1453b4fd996c72ece58f8cb4468ec70e35ade11f) uses `/composer`.

Please try to use the following configuration. It contains a custom cache (which needs a custom name!) that puts the customized composer folder in the cache:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    develop:
    - step:
        caches:
          - composer-custom

definitions:
  caches:
    composer-custom: /composer/cache
```

As you can see on https://bitbucket.org/haasenico/composer-cache/addon/pipelines/home#!/results/4, the cache is used and seems to work for my short example

Comment: the above syntax doesn't work, if you put it into the pipeline yaml validator, you'll get [this](https://i.imgur.com/67C8PoB.png) error message: expected a string but found a mapping. I tried to override the definition of the composer cache (see update to question) but that didn't work either

Comment: Oh yeah, got that wrong. Have you tried using the custom cache definition section provided in the documentation?

Comment: yes I have also didn't work (see update). I'll have to either make the composer directory in the docker image point to the same usual place, or somehow find a way to point the composer installation to the custom cache directory

Comment: @abbood I've worked out a working example and edited my answer. Looks like you cannot override the directory for the default composer cache, but have to add another one under a different name

Comment: and how to you make the `composer install` command find its cache inside `composer-custom`? please show me your `composer install` script command in your working example

Comment: @abbood the Bitbucket link shows everything that is needed: I haven’t used anything to make that work

Comment: nico i can confirm your code works on its own, but i'm trying to integate it into my own code/composer.json.. see update 2

Comment: it worked! i'll award you the correct answer, but i'll put my own answer just for my own reference as well

Comment: Custom cache works out of the box. I assume pipelines just caches the contents of `/composer/cache` between builds, no matter what is in there.

Answer (score 3):

To make this work I basically followed Nico Haase's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59542186/766570), but I also had to do the following:

- remove `"cache-dir": "~/.cache/composer"` from my composer.json
- ensure that the cache file saved is in *sync* with whatever is going on in composer.json.. you cannot ask composer.json to load the dependencies from a cache file that has irrelevant content. To do this, I simply deleted all caches file and started again, it worked this time!

[image]